# Sklearn Pipeline - How to inherit get_params in custom Transformer (not Estimator)

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a pipeline in scikit-learn that uses a custom transformer I define like below:

```
class MyPipelineTransformer(TransformerMixin):
```

which defines functions

```
__init__, fit() and transform()
```

However, when I use the pipeline inside RandomizedSearchCV, I get the following error:

> 'MyPipelineTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_params'

I've read online (e.g. links below)

[(Python - sklearn) How to pass parameters to the customize ModelTransformer class by gridsearchcv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810855/python-sklearn-how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-customize-modeltransformer-clas)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

that I could get 'get_params' by inheriting from BaseEstimator, instead of my current code inheriting just from TransformerMixin. But my transformer is not an estimator. Is there any downside to having a non-estimator inherit from BaseEstimator? Or is that the recommended way to get get_params for any transformer (estimator or not) in a pipeline?

Comment: I upvoted, and I don't know the answer to your question, but you should name classes using UpperCamelCase. Please, just do it for me. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Thanks, Juanpa. You are correct. Edited accordingly https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: @MaxPower Is your `MyPipelineTransformer` encapsulating several steps in a pipeline?

Comment: This question was about a transformer which was a component of a larger sklearn pipeline

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it looks like this is the standard way of achieving this. For example [in the source for `sklearn.preprocessing`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py#L14) we have

```
class FunctionTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin)
```

Comment: Note also that `__init__` needs to be set up properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68926629/14278409