# scikit-learn AttributeError in custom transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a transformer that changes types of columns from "object" to "category", so I created custom class for that:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class ChangeToCategory(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, to_categories = None):
        self.to_categories_ = to_categories
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X_ = X.copy()
        for cat in self.to_categories_:
            X_[cat] = X_[cat].astype("category")
        return X_
```

But I'm getting error when I try to create object of this class:

```
ChangeToCategory(to_categories=["Sex", "Embarked"])
AttributeError: 'ChangeToCategory' object has no attribute 'to_categories'
```

What am I doing wrong? Based on error, I assume that it somewhere try to call attribute "to_categories", but I use attribute "to_categories_" - with underscore, and without is variable from init, which I don't call anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I found there I was wrong. From [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html) you must initialize all estimator parameters as attributes of the class.

> In addition, every keyword argument accepted by **init** should correspond to an attribute on the instance. Scikit-learn relies on this to find the relevant attributes to set on an estimator when doing model selection.

Comment: Specially important when using `Pipeline`s ! Cheers

Comment: To be more explicit: Every keyword argument accepted by `init` should correspond to an attribute on the instance with _exactly the same name_. In this case, `to_categories` instead of `to_categories_`