# Inherit from the SciKit FunctionTransformer

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn

I would like to use `FunctionTransformer` and at the same time provide a simple API and hide the additional details. Specifically, I'd like to be able to provide a `Custom_Trans` class as shown below. So, instead of `trans1`, which works fine, the user should be able to use `trans2` which fails at the moment:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import numpy as np

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=0.1)

def func(X, a, b):
    return X[:,a:b]

class Custom_Trans(preprocessing.FunctionTransformer):
    def __init__(self, ind0, ind1):
        super().__init__(
            func=func,
            kw_args={
                "a": ind0,
                "b": ind1
            }
        )

trans1 = preprocessing.FunctionTransformer( 
    func=func,
    kw_args={
        "a": 0,
        "b": 50
    }
)

trans2 = Custom_Trans(0,50)

pipe1 = Pipeline(
    steps=[
           ('custom', trans1),
           ('linear', LinearRegression())
         ]
)

pipe2 = Pipeline(
    steps=[
           ('custom', trans2),
           ('linear', LinearRegression())
          ]
)

print(model_selection.cross_val_score(
    pipe1, X, y, cv=3,)
)

print(model_selection.cross_val_score(
    pipe2, X, y, cv=3,)
)
```

This is what I get:

```py
[0.99999331 0.99999671 0.99999772]
...sklearn/base.py:209: FutureWarning: From version 0.24, get_params will raise an
AttributeError if a parameter cannot be retrieved as an instance attribute. 
Previously it would return None.
warnings.warn('From version 0.24, get_params will raise an '
...
[0.99999331 0.99999671 0.99999772]
```

I kinda know that it's related to estimator cloning, but I don't know how to fix it. E.g [this post](https://www.mbrouns.com/posts/2020-01-26-sklearns-init/) says that

> there should be no logic, not even input validation, in an estimators
>   **init**. The logic should be put where the parameters are used, which is typically in fit

but in this case, I need to pass the parameters to the superclass. There is no way to put the logic in the `fit()`. 
What can I do?

Comment: Just saw this note in the `BaseEstimator` _All estimators should specify all the parameters that can be set at the class level in their __init__ as explicit keyword arguments (no *args or **kwargs)._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get 'get_params' by inheriting from BaseEstimator.

```
class FunctionTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin)
```

[How to pass parameters to the customize modeltransformer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810855/python-sklearn-how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-customize-modeltransformer-clas)

[inherit from function_transformer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py#L14)

[custom transformers](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-transformers-and-ml-data-pipelines-with-python-20ea2a7adb65)

You have this in base:

```
def get_params(self, deep=True):
        """
        Get parameters for this estimator.
        Parameters
        ----------
        deep : bool, default=True
            If True, will return the parameters for this estimator and
            contained subobjects that are estimators.
        Returns
```

Change your code:

```
trans1 = dict(
    functiontransformer__kw_args=[
        {'ind0': None},
        {'ind0': [1]}
    ]
)

class Custom_Trans(preprocessing.FunctionTransformer): 
    def __init__(self, ind0, ind1, deep=True): 
        super().__init__( func=func, kw_args={ "a": ind0, "b": ind1 } ) 
        self.ind0 = ind0
        self.ind1 = ind1
        self.deep = True
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm already inheriting from `FunctionTransformer`, so `trans2` has `get_prams()` the problem is that it returns `{'ind0': None, 'ind1': None}`

Comment: I think get_params() function looks at the init arguments to figure out what the class parameters are and then suppose that they have same  names as the internal variable names.

Comment: It is your problem at line 209: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/94d8911310b7ec9cb6be2752d42b0cbd4c003c93/sklearn/base.py#L187

Comment: true. I remember reading this before, so it's basically a bug in SciKit

Comment: Lets simply change your __init__

Comment: I did rename `a` and `b` to `ind0` and `ind1`, but still getting `None` and the same warning/error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214615/discussion-between-mahsa-hassankashi-and-towi-parallelism).

Comment: thanks. I don't need the Base. Can you please update your answer? It should be like: ```class Custom_Trans(preprocessing.FunctionTransformer):
    def __init__(self, ind0, ind1):
        super().__init__(
            func=func,
            kw_args={
                "a": ind0,
                "b": ind1
            }
        )
        self.ind0 = ind0
        self.ind1 = ind1
```

I shall accept your answer, but I'll just wait a few hours to see if someone from the SciKit can confirm that they'll change this method in the future. Thanks.